# Collecting inputs into the array

Tags: javascript, php

I have got the following code which is input form.

```
<div class="input_wrap">
       <div class="questions-field row">
              <label class="col-md-12" for="">
                <input type="text" name="questions[]" class="form-control">
            </label>
       </div>
       <button class="add_field_button">Add More input </button>
</div>
```

I am using jQuery to generate new inputs after clicking on button. JS looks like as follow:

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove_field", function () {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });

$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".add_field_button").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".input_wrap>div").append('<label class="col-md-12"for=""><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><input type="text" name="questions[]" class="form-control col-md-10"></label>'); //add input box
            });
        });
```

So everythings works fine, **i use PHP to get array ( questions[] ) which contain filled inputs**.

So when i filled up 5 inputs i get array that looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => rgerg
    [1] => qwd
    [2] => ffr
    [3] => fffffffffffffff
    [4] => ggggggggggggg
)
```

What i want is to add NOT just one but 2 inputs dynamically where first one would be the question and  second one the answer. Something like:

```
 Array
        (
            [0] => array('rgerg','text associated to rgerg')
            [1] => array('qwd','text associated to qwd')
            [2] => array('ffr','text associated to ffr')
            .
            .
            .
        )
```

how it can be done ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably better to get `questions[0] => 'rgerg'` and `answers[0] => 'text associated to rgerg'`

Comment: Where is your answer input, how it should be laid off in the html?

Comment: @TheAlpha there is not any answer input, but it may look like the same as question input but thing is how to associate them, actually thinking about 
AbraCadaver answer

Comment: Quite easy to do it if you keep track of the number of questions, i.e. `questions[1]`, `questions[2]`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could associate question with corresponding answer if you give both fields same index in their names. For example, with this `name` attributes

Question:

```
<input type="text" name="questions[0][]" value="Question 1" />
```

Answer:

```
<input type="text" name="questions[0][]" value="Answer 1" />
```

(yes, names are absolutely the same)

Resulting `$_POST` in PHP side will have desired structure:

```
Array
(
    [questions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Question 1
                    [1] => Answer 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Question 2
                    [1] => Answer 2
                )

        )

)
```

Of course you need to increment index in the name with each question:

```
name="questions[0][]" // First question
name="questions[1][]" // Second question
name="questions[2][]" // Third question
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add question and corresponding answer as mentioned below:

```
<input type="text" name="quiz[0][question]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="quiz[0][answer]" class="form-control">

<input type="text" name="quiz[1][question]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="quiz[1][answer]" class="form-control">

<input type="text" name="quiz[2][question]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="quiz[2][answer]" class="form-control">
```

> $_POST will return below array:

```
Array
(
    [quiz] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question] => ques1
                    [answer] => ans1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question] => ques2
                    [answer] => ans2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question] => ques3
                    [answer] => ans3
                )

        )
)
```